What could have changed that caused guests not to be able access a Slack channel anymore?
I have a Slack account  through my organization. I created a Slack channel and  invited 2 guests outside my organization to join my channel. They used to be  able to use the Slack channel for 2 weeks, but since today, the 2 guests can't access the channel anymore.
What could have changed that caused the 2 guests not to be able access the channel anymore? I still see the 2 guests  as members of the channel:

The guests don't see any error message when trying to access the channel:

I can't see any error because it redirects me to other slack channels that I have.

